# Display GA4 event parameter in google data studio

Tags: events, google-tag-manager, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I upgraded to Google Analytics 4 and struggle to display event parameters in Google Data Studio. I created an event parameter in Google Tag Manager to track the ID of a link. Now I want to display a table in Google Data Studio to show how many clicks I have for each ID in the last 30 days.
In GA4 it just shows the event parameters of the last 30 minutes
[image: Event parameters last 30 minutes]

That's why I tried to display it in Data Studio. But I have no idea how to do that.
In Universal analytics it was no problem but GA4 really gives me a hard time.

**UPDATE:**
I could solve it with BigQuery. I activated BigQuery in my console, connected it with my analytics acount, connected BigQuery with Data Studio and created a custom Query.

Comment: You can register each of those event parameters as custom definitions in GA4. Then, you can create reports on those custom definitions in Data Studio. Here is an example of that process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65623776/14466144.

Answer (score 8):

The solution via BigQuery is one way.

The other option would be to to create a custom dimension, which is based on your custom event parameter. The reason is that Google Analytics 4 event parameters are currently not being synched with Google Data Studio - but only Google Analytics 4 dimensions are.

In the Google Analytics 4 interface, you can go to *Configure > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions* and create an event-scoped custom dimension based on the event parameter `affiliate`.
Then, after updating your Google Data Studio data source, you should be able to access the new dimension in Google Data Studio.

Comment: I followed the instructions, but the parameter is still not showing. Here is the event I am sending: `gtag('event', `event-direct`, {videoId: 5});`. So I added `videoId` but I cannot show the list with various values and the count of each. Any suggestion?

Comment: @mPrinC, did you solve the issue with showing the parameter value/count? Having the same issue here.

Comment: Hi, @korrekorre, I gave up, it was all too hacky, and basically what I did was to go for BigQuery, there after learning language extensions, all was more natural; just forward the data stream to BigQuery and process it

Answer (score -1):

You can display event parameter in Google Data Studio with a [filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) like this:

```
Include -> Page title and screen name > contains -> affiliate
```